# TikZ/Circuitikz: change the color of dipchip pin numbers?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I am trying to use the tikz package to define a node and am confused about a few settings one of which is specific to the package `circuitikz` that

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzstyle{ic} = [
  dipchip,
  external pins width=0.3,
  external pad fraction=4,
  fill=black!70,
  draw=black,
  text=white,
  thin,
  align=center % or text centered?
]

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[ic, num pins=14] at (0,0) {7400}; % or {\small\ttfamily 7400}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have the following questions related to the styling that I want to apply:

1. I want to change the color of the pin numbers (encircled in red) to white - I tried setting the TikZ `text` and `draw` options in the node style but it did not work as intended. Is there any way in which this can be done?
2. What is the difference between the `text=align` option and the `text centered` option?
3. Can the font settings, in this case `{\small\ttfamily ...}` be applied in the `text` option to the `tikzstyle` setting? So something like `text={\small\ttfamily}` ?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As to point 1, you can hack in an overlaid number with `\node[white] at (-.696,1.668) {\tiny 1};`  Not ideal, I realize.  You can allow a bit more slop if you use a colorbox: `\node[white] at (-.696,1.668) {\tiny\fboxsep=1pt \colorbox{black!70}{1}};`

Comment: My understanding is that [align=center] causes the text to be put inside a tabular [@{}c@{}].  With only one line, it should make no difference whatsoever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please, do not make multiple questions in one entry!

About the first one, if you say (see manual, page 155)

```latex
\ctikzset{multipoles/font={\color{white}\tiny}}
```

you'll have the numbers in white (you can use a `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}` to keep it local).

`align` is  not `circuitikz`-specific, it's general, and you can see it in action if you have more than one line in the node's text. `text centered`, I do not know what it is.

For applying a font generally, you can always say `every node/.style={font=\small}`.

Here is an example:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{ic/.style={
  dipchip,
  external pins width=0.3,
  external pad fraction=4,
  fill=black!70,
  draw=black,
  text=white,
  thin,
  align=center,% try left or right
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={font=\small}]
  \ctikzset{multipoles/font={\color{white}\tiny}}
  \node[ic, num pins=14] at (0,0) {7400 \\ xyz}; % or {\small\ttfamily 7400}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(BTW: I subsitued the deprecated `tikzstyle` with the modern form.)

You can also put all your changes locally in the `ic` style:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\tikzset{ic/.style={
  dipchip,
  external pins width=0.3,
  external pad fraction=4,
  fill=black!70,
  draw=black,
  text=white,
  thin,
  align=center,% try left or right
  font=\small,
  circuitikz/multipoles/font={\color{white}\tiny},
}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[ic, num pins=14] at (0,0) {7400 \\ xyz}; % or {\small\ttfamily 7400}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(same result)